# Oracle: Creating new database remove existing user

Tags: oracle

I used Database Configuration Assistant to create new database but afterwards notice all exsiting database user disappeared. Please help!

Comment: Why would there be existing users in a new database? Really not sure what you mean.

Comment: I logged in as sys then perform select username from all_users and previous exisiting usernames are gone

Comment: But which previous existing usernames? Is this in the new database or some other database - as mmmmmpie suggested, are you logged into the wrong place? Or did you recreate (overwrite) an existing database? Or you just haven't recreated your own users in your new database?

Comment: I got it. U guys are right. Logged in to the new db.. i switch to other db then i can see the user..I am new to oracle, its a bit confusing, but over time getting clearer.. thx to all of u guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how you are checking the users?

```
run > cmd

set ORACLE_sid=<database_name_here>

sqlplus / as sysdba

select username from dba_users;
```

Comment: I logged in as sys then perform 'select username from all_users;'

Answer (score 0):

I bet you've created the new database and are logged into it instead of the existing instance (maybe?)
Check which database you are in 1 of two ways:
`echo $ORACLE_SID` or `select name from v$database;`
If you find you are logged into the new instance find your old one and switch to it:
Find all SID's installed in your environment: `cat /etc/oratab`
Switch to it: `. oraenv` then enter in the appropriate SID you found in the oratab.

Comment: How to switch to another instance in windows?

Comment: I got it ..thx..one more question: how to list all existing instances?

Comment: run> services.msc  then list services running with name starts with OracleService . For example OracleServiceORCL <orcl is the name of the Instance>